# ReactJS: Using React Owl Carousel updating

Tags: reactjs

So my issue has to do with component updates.

I have the OwlCarousel component:

```
<OwlCarousel> 
  {this.loadPhotoComponent()} // add a new photo component from MongoDB object
</OwlCarousel>
```

With each photo component, I include a checkbox to allow display or not. Just changes a boolean in the mongo database. However, every time I click it, I think it resets the OwlCarousel. Is there a way to stop this from happening, maybe

```
shouldComponentUpdate()
```

but, I'm a bit lost on how to use this with each component? Or maybe I can setState to be the mongo object and then...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue using jsfiddle? It's hard to help you without seeing your code.

Comment: @biphobe Unfortunately, I'm not skilled enough to reproduce this issue on jsfiddle. The major problem being, that I am getting a cursor from mongoDB and in jsfiddle, I would have to setState as an array of objects, which won't be the same context...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone looking at this later. The issue was actually my TrackerReact package. It will re-render everything if the collection changes... I was able to keep the TrackerReact package, but I ended up using `shouldComponentUpdate() { return false; }` on the parent component and it was fine.